# jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js X-Axis sort with 2hour parameters and tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have use this jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js plugin and would like to have on X axis sorting by 0h 2h 4h 6h 8h 10h 12h 14h 16h 18h 20h 22h 24h and on Y axis sorting by bandwidth....and need to show in tooltip US_CH2 (channel number that corresponds to data returned from server). My data returned from server is this:

```
var prevYear = [
        ["2011-08-02 00:00:00 US_CH1",398], 
        ["2011-08-02 06:00:00 US_CH2",255.25], 
        ["2011-08-02 12:00:00 US_CH3",263.9], 
        ["2011-08-02 18:00:00 US_CH4",154.24], 
        ["2011-08-02 23:00:00 US_CH5",210.18], 
        ["2011-08-02 24:00:00 US_CH6",210.18]];

    var currYear = [
        ["2011-08-02 00:00:00 US_CH1",796.01], 
        ["2011-08-02 06:00:00 US_CH2",510.5], 
        ["2011-08-02 12:00:00 US_CH3",527.8], 
        ["2011-08-02 18:00:00 US_CH4",208.48], 
        ["2011-08-02 24:00:00 US_CH5",420.36]];
```

As you can see i have prevYear (that is YELLOW in graph) and currYear (that is BLUE in graph).

So here is my code that i have try but it is not working as it should be:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.jqplot._noToImageButton = true;
        var prevYear = [
            ["2011-08-02 00:00:00 US_CH1",398], 
            ["2011-08-02 06:00:00 US_CH2",255.25], 
            ["2011-08-02 12:00:00 US_CH3",263.9], 
            ["2011-08-02 18:00:00 US_CH4",154.24], 
            ["2011-08-02 23:00:00 US_CH5",210.18], 
            ["2011-08-02 24:00:00 US_CH6",210.18]];

    var currYear = [
        ["2011-08-02 00:00:00 US_CH1",796.01], 
        ["2011-08-02 06:00:00 US_CH2",510.5], 
        ["2011-08-02 12:00:00 US_CH3",527.8], 
        ["2011-08-02 18:00:00 US_CH4",208.48], 
        ["2011-08-02 24:00:00 US_CH5",420.36]];

        var plot1 = $.jqplot("chart2", [prevYear, currYear], {
            seriesColors: ["rgba(78, 135, 194, 0.7)", "rgb(211, 235, 59)"],
            title: 'Watched Channels & Bandwidth',
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 1,
                tooltipOffset: 9
            },
            grid: {
                background: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.0)',
                drawBorder: false,
                shadow: false,
                gridLineColor: '#666666',
                gridLineWidth: 2
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                placement: 'outside'
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                rendererOptions: {
                    smooth: true,
                    animation: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                showMarker: true
            },
            series: [
                {
                    fill: true,
                    label: '2010'
                },
                {
                    label: '2011'
                }
            ],
            axesDefaults: {
                rendererOptions: {
                    baselineWidth: 1.5,
                    baselineColor: '#444444',
                    drawBaseline: false
                }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                     tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%H:%Mh",
                        angle: -30,
                        textColor: '#dddddd'
                    },
                    drawMajorGridlines: false
                 },
                 yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
                    pad: 0,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        minorTicks: 4
                    },
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%'d",
                        showMark: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });

           $('.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip').addClass('ui-corner-all')
         });
```

And want to show in tooltip US_CH2 when mouse over on Marker.

Here is screenshoot of what i want to make:

http://postimg.org/image/k69qecfnl/